# Weird /proc/kallsyms issue

Tags: linux, kernel

I had exported couple of functions in a kernel module through EXPORT_SYMBOL.
To my surprise **one** of the functions was not showing up in /proc/kallsyms.
The weird part is that if I change the name of the exported function, it shows up!

Please note:
1. I have CONFIG_KALLSYMS enabled in the kernel. Also, I'm exporting a function, not variables. 
2. The function was not defined as static.
3. Rebooting the machine and retrying did not help.

Though I've worked around the problem by changing the name, what bothers me is that I still do not understand why the problem occurred in the first place.

I would appreciate if someone could provide pointers to at least how to go about debugging this sort of problem.
If it helps, I'm using kernel 2.6.32 with CONFIG_KALLSYMS enabled and CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL disabled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. If your module is open source, could you provide its code here? It would be easier to see what is going on this way. 2. Does the problem show up if you remove everything from your module except init/exit, necessary declarations and those two functions it exports?

Comment: Eugene, appreciate your response. Unfortunately the module is not opensource. I'll try and reproduce this problem in a dummy module and let you know.

Comment: enable `CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL`